# ftpwebrequest for sFTP in VB.nET

Tags: vb.net, sftp

I've  been able to successfully use ftpwebrequest for uploading and downloading files via standard ftp protocol.

I thought I would be able to use .EnableSSL = True but I still can't connect to the sFTP site.

Research has indicated that .NET libraries don't natively support sFTP - can anyone provide some insight on transferring a file via sFTP?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To use SFTP <strike>or FTP Over SSL</strike> you need to use third party libraries as it is not possible to do with inbuilt .NET classes.

Comment: Any recommendations on which 3rd party tool?  I've found a few which aren't free so I'd like to make sure I'm looking at a set of tools that are appropriate..

Comment: While the answer is true regarding SFTP (SSH File Transfer Protocol), for FTP over TLS/SSL, you can use `FtpWebRequest` (with `EnableSSL`).

Comment: @GeorgeVaisey We're using Chilkat.NET, but there may be better ones. Maybe read some reviews?

Comment: I have been reading reviews and everyone looks fairly similar but don't appear to have been updated or supported in some time.  Was hoping to take the recommendation of others to get a solution that worked well without having to live thru the pain of others.